# Wordpress Site Monitoring software / service

Tags: wordpress, uptime, server-monitoring

What do you use to monitor the uptime / performance of your websites, specifically those based on a PHP/MySQL platform like Wordpress?

I'm looking for something that alerts me if the site is down, or performing too slowly, and has some useful (not volumeous!) charts showing me any potential problems, and what to do about them.

Thanks!

Comment: Try https://www.testomato.com/
Here is the tutorial, on how to monitor WordPress website: https://blog.testomato.com/how-to-automatically-monitor-a-wordpress-website-using-testomato/

Answer (score 4):

We along with the usual [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/), we use [Pingdom](http://pingdom.com/). It comes with lots of default checks.

For example it also reports how fast your website is or since they employ tests from different locations you get a nice graph how accessible your website was. To put some sense into it, add a reference check (e.g. google) and see how you perform.

Aside from HTTP etc. you can also check other services (mail, database, etc.). If they are not reachable from the outside, you can always create a script that outputs a standard "OK" and have Pingdom check on that, and report back if the output changed.

I should add that Pingdom is not a free service. But we've been using them for 10 months now and they haven't troubled us. :)

Comment: But pingdom has a very fast upsell response, which kind of turned me off.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at Zabbix

http://www.zabbix.com/

- WEB performance monitoring
- WEB availability monitoring
- Support of POST and GET methods

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Insping](https://www.insping.com/) also

1. performance monitoring
2. availability monitoring
3. e-mail and SMS alerts